# Why JIT is not allowed in iOS? Can we enable it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spidermonkey

I am trying to use Spidermonkey and it uses JIT to some extent and that is breaking some functionality.I came to know that Apple does not allow JIT due to some security reasons?

Can someone explain what are those possible security reasons?
Also is there any way to enable it for testing purposes?